# BeanIO: one to many relationship reading from flat file

Tags: flat-file, bean-io

I have performance issue with reading one to many relation sent in flat file eg:

```
RE IMS001 D12
RE IMS001 D13
RE IMS002 D14
```

from above flat file position `4-9` is `employeeID` and `11-13` is Department information.
so from row 1 : `employeeID=IMS001` and `departmentGroup=D` `departmentNumber=12`
but one **employee can have multiple department** so from the second row for the same `employeeID` `IMS001` there is a `departmentGroup=D` `departmentNumber=13`

i have xml mapping as below

```
    <record name="employee" maxLength="51" class="com.a.EmployeeDTO">
        <field name="employeeId" position="4" length="6" trim="false" />
       <segment name="departments" class="com.a.DepartmentDTO"
                                       collection="list" minOccurs="1" >
          <field name="departmentGroup" position="11" length="1" trim="false" />
          <field name="departmentNumber" position="12" length="2" trim="false" />
       </segment>
   </record>
```

DTOs:

```
Class EmployeeDTO{
private employeeId;
private List<Department> departments = new ArrayList<Department>;
}

Class DepartmentDTO{
private departmentGroup;
private departmentNumber;
}
```

with this i'm able read line by line with one employeeID connected to one Department. but if you see the full file for a `employeeID=IMS001` there are two departments. how to read this relation effectively ? i don't want to do too many get calls on db to check whether department is inserted already.

Comment: Your code does not match the mapping file and have compile failures as it is at the moment, although it is obvious what it should be, make sure that you don't confuse matters by supplying incorrect code or mapping files.

Comment: please read the BeanIO user guide (http://beanio.org/2.1/docs/reference/index.html). Position starts at 0 and fix your mapping file please. Give us a working example that makes it easier for us to help.